# read images from my external storage file into native c ( openCV) Android

Tags: java, android, opencv, external, native

I need to pass some data from java to OpenCV, I tried saving it into the external storage files, I know how to read it in java, but I don't know how to read it in opencv (native c)
 so I guess the question is, How can I read some images from my external storage file (knowing the path) into native c ( openCV), I need the pixel value of the images for feature extraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you mind reading data on the java side ad then pass that `byte[]` array onto the `JNI` side?

```
File f = new File("/path");
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(f);

WritableRaster raster = bufferedImage.getRaster();
DataBufferByte data = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();

byte[] array = data.getData();

invokeJNIMethodWithOpenCL(array);


//....
private native void invokeJNIMethodWithOpenCL(byte[] array);
```